# Cell colour overlapping cell borders

Tags: tables, color, rules

This code makes the borders disappear in the coloured cells. How do I get the borders back? Have tried `hhline` and this doesn't work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{lll}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Table}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}}                              &                       \\
                               & a                                                          & b                     \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{a}             & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]     {FE0000}\textit{}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textit{b}}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]        {CD9934}}          & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thuis is known issue with `\cline{...}` and `colortbl`. In such situations lines from package `hhline` is handy:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hhline}
\newcommand\mc[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{r|c|c|}
\mc{\textbf{Table}}     & \mc{}                     & \mc{}     \\
\mc{}                   & \mc{a}                    & \mc{b}    \\ 
    \hhline{~|-|-|}
\textit{a}              & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}  &           \\ 
    \hhline{~|-|-|}
\textit{b}              & \cellcolor[HTML]{CD9934}  &            \\ 
    \hhline{~|-|-|}
\end{tabular}%
}

or 

\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{tabular}{|r|c|c|}
\mc{\textbf{Table}}     & \mc{}                     & \mc{}     \\
\mc{}                   & \mc{a}                    & \mc{b}    \\
    \hhline{-|-|-|}
\textit{a}              & \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}  &           \\
    \hhline{-|-|-|}
\textit{b}              & \cellcolor[HTML]{CD9934}  &            \\
    \hhline{-|-|-|}
\end{tabular}%
}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The package `nicematrix` has tools designed to address that kind of problem.

In your code, I have replaced `{tabular}` by `{NiceTabular}` with the key `color-inside` (that key specifies that there will be color instructions in the tabular).

Of course, I have loaded `nicematrix` (and unloaded several unused packages).

The output is as expected.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{NiceTabular}{lll}[color-inside]
\multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{Table}} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{\textbf{}} & \\
                          & a                                                & b                     \\ \cline{2-3} 
\multicolumn{1}{l|}{a}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000}\textit{}} & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\multicolumn{1}{|l|}{\textit{b}}   & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{\cellcolor[HTML]{CD9934}}    & \multicolumn{1}{l|}{} \\ \hline
\end{NiceTabular}%
}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the first code]

However, the output is not perfect (there is a small problem of connexion between two rules).

`nicematrix` has tools for the rules which will avoid that problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{%
\begin{NiceTabular}{lll}[color-inside]
\Block[c]{}{\textbf{Table}} \\
           & a                        & b \\ 
a          & \Block[hvlines]{1-2}{} \cellcolor[HTML]{FE0000} \\
\Block[hvlines]{1-3}{}
\textit{b} & \cellcolor[HTML]{CD9934} \\
\end{NiceTabular}%
}
\caption{My caption}
\label{my-label}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the second code]