# How does \hhline work?

Tags: cellcolor

I'm new using LaTeX and I want to learn how should I use the `\hhline` when I have problems with `\cellcolor` command. How does the `\hhline` work? I saw differents ways to use but I don't understand

For  example:
`\hhline{bla bla}`  --- how does it work?

If I have colored cells, where color overwrites borders of cell A and cell B, what should I do?

Comment: A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/355974/hhline-and-cell-color-problems-revisited or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366873/cell-colour-overlapping-cell-borders/366881#366881. For further help please show us what you try so far-

Comment: Run `texdoc hhline`, read the page 1 and play with the example of page 2.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 6):

See

```
texdoc hhline
```

for the manual which has lots of examples but if you have a 4 column table with `\cline{2-3}` putting a line over columns 2 and 3, then the equivalent `\hhline` to replace the `\cline` is

```
\hhline{~--~}
```

which puts no line `~` in column one, then two columns with a single line `-` then a final column with no line.

But before doing that are you really sure that you want lines and coloured panels? I wrote both `colortbl` and `hhline` packages and I'm not sure I'd use them both in the same document (other than in joke examples in the `hhline` manual)