# multirow with color does not work properly

Tags: tables, multirow, rowcolor

First, there is not any error message, but I have this problem in which I want to merge rows horizontally, but I do not know why the text appears like that:

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\arrayrulecolor{gray}
\caption{Statistics}\label{tab8}
\rowcolors{2}{gray!50}{white!10}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|} 
\hline  
 \multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{country}} &
\multirow{2}{*}{\textbf{GDP}} &
\multicolumn{2}{|c|}{\textbf{Sex}} \\
& & \textbf{male} & \textbf{female} \\
 A&B&C&D\\ 
 A&B&C&D\\ 
 A&B&C&D\\ 
 \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
\end{document}
```

I want the merged cells to be colored with only one color.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You should provide a complete MWE (minimal working example) with the `\document{classe}`, `\usepackage{...}`, etc.

Comment: I already added all packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `\multirow{-2}{*}{text}` you can properly colorize the background of the two rows.

Related question: [\rowcolor for a \multirow](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/269547/rowcolor-for-a-multirow)

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{multirow}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\arrayrulecolor{gray}
\caption{Statistics}\label{tab8}
\rowcolors{3}{white}{gray!20}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|c|}

\hline

\rowcolor{gray!35}

& & \multicolumn{2}{c|}{\textbf{Sex}}\\

\rowcolor{gray!35}

\multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{country}} &
\multirow{-2}{*}{\textbf{GDP}} &
\textbf{male} & \textbf{female}\\

\hline

Row 1 & & &\\
Row 2 & & &\\
Row 3 & & &\\
Row 4 & & &\\

\hline

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: table preview]

Comment: Thank you for your help but there is no line under Sex column, how can I show it up?

Comment: I don't know a way to do it, but I'd advise you to not do it. These are the reasons:
[problem with cline in multirow, colored tabular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58786996/problem-with-cline-in-multirow-colored-tabular) and [How does \hhline work?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/367699/how-does-hhline-work)

Answer (score 2):

The environment `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix` has a command `\rowcolors` able to color rows with alternance while respecting the blocks (with the key `respect-blocks`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx,color}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{caption}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\arrayrulecolor{gray}
\caption{Statistics}
\begin{NiceTabular}{|cccc|} 
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolors{1}{gray!50}{white!10}[respect-blocks]
\Body
  \Hline
  \RowStyle[bold,nb-rows=2]{}
  \Block{2-1}{country} &
  \Block{2-1}{GDP} & \Block{1-2}{Sex} \\
  & & male & female \\
  A&B&C&D\\ 
  A&B&C&D\\ 
  A&B&C&D\\ 
  \Hline
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]